# Wordpress - если в "wp-content" нет такого файла, то отдать за место 404 код ответа 403. В htacess может как прописать?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

На сайте Wordpress имеется папка "wp-content", там лежат плагины, переводы и т.д. Тут всё стандартно.

В данной папке я создал файл `.htaccess` с таким содержанием :

```
Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|cur)$">
    Allow from all
    </Files>
```

Теперь если сканирующий бот (ищущий уязвимые плагины) находит там интересующий его txt, php и прочее, то выдаётся 403 страница, которую отдаёт сервер. 
А вот если не находит (сканируя несуществующий путь), то выдаётся 404 страница, причём выводит её сам Wordpress.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при сканировании несуществующих файлов и путей в папке "wp-content" (и её подпапках, естественно) отдавалась не 404 ошибка, а тоже 403?

Comment: Если хорошо подумать, то это ВСЁ не только не нужно, но и может навредить сайту. Но дело хозяйское.. Ели нечем больше заняться - удачи.

Comment: Чем может навредить? За место сарказма можно было бы и изложить свою позицию. Понятно, что плагины нужно обновлять, как и движок. Но чем плохо отдавать 403 ошибку по отсутствию файлов в этой и вложенных в неё папок?! Лучше, когда всем ботам отдаётся 403 ошибка, нежели 403 только от имеющихся файлов и 404 вовсе отсутствующих! Не надо создавать даже косвенное свидетельство наличия и отсутствия используемых плагинов! Безопасности НИКОГДА не бывает много!

Comment: Не знаю за какое место, но тут не форум, чтобы "излагать позиции"  в расширенном варианте (разжевывать основы работы серверов, интернета, ботов, безопасности и тд).

Comment: И уж точно это не место для сарказма и оскорблений. Я хорошо подумал, прежде чем задать данный вопрос. Я очень бы хотел услышать решение, за тем и писал этот вопрос. Не надо словоблудить,если нет никакого желания помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /403.php
```

**403.php**

```
<?php
// здесь контент для 403 страницы

// возвращаем 403 статус браузеру
http_response_code(403);
?>
```

Чтобы отдавать 403 для всех запросов к директории:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]
```

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /403.php добавил эту строчку в .htaccess, что находится в папке wp-content и создал тот файл - не действует. Может потому что LiteSpeed сервер.
         
Rewrite работает, но все запросы переадресовать никак нельзя, там же css стили темы, плагинов.

Comment: Какая версия PHP? Если менее 5.4 - см функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-response-code.php (пример)

Comment: Я конечно не программист, но мне кажется, что указанная директива ErrorDocument 404 /403.php в файле .htaccess, что находится в директории wp-content не используется. Ведь страница с 404 ошибкой отдаётся самим движком Wordpress. Т.е. к примеру введя http://site.ru/wp-content/123456 - выскочит 404, но шаблона Wordpress, с меню и прочим. На сервере есть файл 404.shtml в корне, и он отдаётся, к примеру, при таком урл http://site.ru/.well-known/apple-app-site-association Мне неизвестно, почему в данном случае движок Wordpress не перехватывает этот запрос..